# What is the most efficient way to get SQL table values?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql, ajax

I wrote some code a while back to retrieve a player's saved score when they logged into the website. It used AJAX, and looked a little something like this:

Javascript:

```
function getHighScore(user){
    $.get("getScore.php?userName="+user,function(data){
        console.log(data);
                output = data;
    });
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$username = strval($_GET['userName']);

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','XXXX','XXXX','XXXX');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
} else {
$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$username."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $wealth = $row['wealth'];

    echo $wealth;

    }
}

mysqli_close($con);
//return $wealth;
?>
```

I was faced with the fact today that I would have to grab a whole bunch of data from a database, so I had a look at the old high score code I wrote. I'll attach a screenshot of what the table looks like that I will be retrieving info from. Anyway, I need to grab info from 6 columns and 10 rows. I need to assign a PHP variable to the data from P1, P2, P3 etc on MON1; P1, P2, P3 etc on TUE1; so on and so forth until we reach P6 on FRI2. I'm really quite new to PHP, so what would be the best way to go around doing this?

I apologise if I worded the question strangely. Feel free to ask if you didn't understand something.

Thank you!

PS: Ignore the P#_WORK columns. I don't need to refer to them right now

https://ibb.co/gq8u5a

Comment: No pictures please. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you use an object to store everything, using the "day" column as key, and as value the P* columns in another. Here's some code you can use right away:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','XXXX','XXXX','XXXX');
if(!$con) exit('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));

$username = $_GET['userName'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE username = '%s'";
$results = $con->query(sprintf($sql, $con->escape_string($username))); // Always escape parameters to prevent SQL injection attacks

$data = new stdClass; // An empty object

while($result = $results->fetch_object()){
    $day = $result->day; // Use the day as the key of the object
    $data->{$day} = $result;
}

// Now we output the results below by accesing the data in a chain-like fashion by accesing the "data" object
echo $data->MON1->P1 . '<br>'; // will output "Geo E"
echo $data->FRI1->P4 . '<br>'; // will output "Maths"
echo $data->THU2->P6 . '<br>'; // will output "DT"
```

Be sure to replace "TABLE" in the SQL query with the actual table name, as that wasn't visible in the screenshot you attached.

Comment: This is perfect - thank you! Except, where you have the SELECT line, you use 'username' when there is no username column - did you mean 'day'?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to tag you. @ablopez

Comment: Since in the original code you posted you referenced a username GET parameter I assumed you still needed to use it, but if you don't need any filtering then don't worry, just change $sql to `$sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE";` and $results to `$results = $con->query($sql);`

Comment: My bad. Should have made it clearer. Thank you! @ablopez

Comment: Hey, back again @ablopez , I was wondering, if I wanted to assign the value of, say, $data->THU2->P6 to a variable, what would be the best way to sends this back to my JS so I can create a JS variable equal to that PHP variable? I would need to do this for ~20 variables in one go. Confused, because I only know how to read a single string that has been outputted.

Comment: To send it back to JS replace the echo's with a single `exit(json_encode($data));` at the end of the script to encode it to JSON, then call the script from JS with an XHR request and parse the response with JSON.parse() to get the "data" object in JS exactly as it was in PHP, and then you can access it in JS as `data.MON1.P1`, `data.FRI1.P4`, etc. for example.

Comment: Haha, you're amazing man. Thanks for the help. I'll go try it now. @ablopez

Comment: When you say XMR, don't you mean XML? @ablopez

Comment: Nope, XHR means XMLHttpRequest, in other words just a good-ol' AJAX request :)

Comment: What would I include inside the JSON.parse()? @ablopez

Comment: The simplest way to get started is with jQuery's getJSON() function (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) which is a quick-and-dirty, solution that gets the job done right away. However, the better practice would be using jQuery's ajax() function using the dataType: 'json' parameter to have jQuery automatically parse the response as JSON, and adding a success and error callback to alert the user of any error that could have happened in the connection or JSON-parsing of the response.

Comment: You'd include the plain-text response received from the XHR, however, please see my new comment above for a simpler solution to get you started.

Comment: Getting an internal server error. Is that syntax in the PHP? @ablopez

Comment: Oops - my bad - fixed it. I get no output with the JSON.parse() by itself. Inside the parenthesis, would I have to include something like $data->THU2->P6? @ablopez

Comment: Got it working, as in I can console.log the entire $data . How do I just access the individual elements like you suggested? I didn't really understand the data.MON1.P1 example

Comment: Sorry. Forgot to tag. @ablopez